# subtracting tuple from integer

Tags: python, int, tuples, subtraction

```
for r in races:
    print r
    print 'Par ',r.par()
    print 'Quarter pars ', r.quarterpars()
    print ''
```

This returns:

```
Par  75,

Quarter pars  Route (50, 57, 73, 86),
```

I need to subtract the quarter pars from par:

```
(75 - 50, 75 - 57, 75 - 73, 75 - 86),

= (25, 18, 2, -11),
```

Par is an `int` and quarter pars is a `tuple`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [82]: quarterPars = (50, 57, 73, 86)

In [83]: par = 75

In [84]: tuple(par-q for q in quarterPars)
Out[84]: (25, 18, 2, -11)
```

Comment: List comprehension like syntax is always recommended :)

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> qp=(50, 57, 73, 86)
>>> p=75
>>> tuple(map(lambda e: p-e, qp))
(25, 18, 2, -11)
```